# Pyspark to convert the date format as yyy-MM-dd

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Can you help with pyspak query to convert the dates as below like in SQL
[image]

Comment: You should have a look at [how Spark handles datetime patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

Spark `Datetime` functions related to convert StringType to/from DateType or TimestampType. For example, unix_timestamp, date_format, to_unix_timestamp, from_unixtime, to_date, to_timestamp, from_utc_timestamp, to_utc_timestamp, etc.

You can use `date_format` function to get the desired date format.

```
select date_format(date '24-03-2022', "yyyy/MM/dd");
```